# what parameters should be added in google map java script so that i can see usage report

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am accessing google map using below java script but  problem is i am unable to see any changes in my usage report.However i see google map being loaded successfully.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&client=client_id&channel=CHANNEL"></script>
```

As you can see i already added my client id and channel

**Is there any additional parameter which i am missing?** 
or is there any other way to load google map which i am not aware of

Comment: The `key` parameter: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

Comment: but key and clientid parameter does not go togather

Comment: Addition to @Duncan's answer.
Google Maps APIs are available for Android or iOS apps, Web browsers, and via HTTP web services. APIs in each platform require a specific type of key. To specify a key, include it as the value of a key parameter when loading the API.

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Are you using Google Maps APIs Premium Plan? Are you asking for Google Maps for Work Usage Report? If you are using Google Maps API Premium Plan, you my access the Google for Work  Usage report. Just log in to the Google for Work Support Portal, in the  left panel, click Maps: Usage Report.

Comment: i wanted to view usage report for different channel but i am unable to view any changes and channel is also not created.So What am i missing?